# MYSQL and PHP search script with word list and links

Tags: php, mysql, string, search, text

I'm working on a search form/script for my website.

For a start every word used in content on my website is stored in a MYSQL table called `words` and it looks something like this :

```
id |  word | title_count | content_count | article_count | photo_count | video_count |
---+-------+-------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
 1 | hello |           3 |             1 |             0 |           1 |           0 |
 2 |  what |           1 |             4 |             1 |           0 |           0 |
```

The `word` and `id` fields are UNIQUE, the fields `title_count` and `content_count` are used to store how many time the word was used in a title or in a main content.
The other `_count` field just say how many time the word was used in an article/photo/video.

I'm not sure if all these count fields will be useful for a search function, but thought it could maybe come in handy.

Then I have multiple linking tables to all the `_count` fields of the `words` table that look like this :

```
id |  word_id | 
---+----------+
43 |        2 |
 7 |        1 |
 7 |        2 |
```

These tables are called : `word_link_title`, `word_link_content`, `word_link_article`, `word_link_photo`, `word_link_video` etc. The `id` field stores the id of a article/photo/video it links to and the `word_id` stores the the ID of the word linked.

Now that I have all of that set up I'm kind of stuck. I don't really have any clear idea how to sort out relevant content based on all these numbers and the research terms.

Something that I plan on doing is a search result page with multiple tabs, one there it would show all the results of the search and then in other tabs it would be separated in articles/photos/videos.

I have no idea if I'm actually on the right path to get something working. Hope someone can help me..

Comment: Have you looked into using mysql's fulltext search?  It's essentially a more advanced version of what you're trying to do here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @SamDufel I'm not sure that really would solve the problem here?  I think he's looking for how to join the meta-data to the assets using this third table that sets up a many to many relationship.  I believe he's going down the right path.  Perhaps I'm just not understanding how you're suggesting to apply a full text search to allow search for categorical results.

Comment: IMO, it's much simpler to add a fulltext index to each table you want to query (articles, content, video, whatever).  The results can be joined / split either with a union or some php.  The advantage of using mysql is that it *already* has logic to emphasize less frequently-used words, and comes with a standard stopword list.  You're basically re-inventing the wheel with a system like this, and adding some serious headaches when you try to maintain the search term index tables manually.

Comment: @SamDufel I have done some research on mysql fulltext search and it is quite interesting, I still like my first idea of the word list & links but I think that I'm going to give the fulltext search a try. 
But I'm wondering is it possible to make the title field words more important than the content words ? If it is possible how do I do this ?

Comment: The results from using `MATCH... AGAINST` in mysql come back as a numeric value - you could, for instance, put a separate fulltext index on the titles vs the bodies, and multiply the search results from the title field X 2, effectively giving them double the weight of the results of the body search.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want, if you want to suggest results, you might want to look into some famous word search algorithms : [Jaro-Winkler](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro-Winkler) is good for short words and [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is good for short words in long text.
You can also use PHP's `similar_text` function for better matching after these previous algorithms.

I posted a bunch of search scripts [here](http://pastebin.com/tmGYGx48) (Jaro-Winkler) and [here](http://pastebin.com/4kcYtq9n) when I built a search engine project, if you want to check it out.

As for the different counts, why not ? You can use the number of occurences to favor some keywords. But careful which ones you insert into your database ! You don't want words like 'the' or 'it' or any other common word corrupting all of this.

EDIT: of course, this means the search will be in PHP, and will have a huge inconvenient of needing to select a large amount of keywords (if not all) from the database. I ended up with a maximum estimated search time of 0.04 seconds, on a database with over 3000 words. So it seems ok =)